# Remove checked for radiolist attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove checked group radio list. How to do that?

```
    <div class="row padding-4">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <input id="SecondaryDiscipline" name="SecondaryDiscipline" type="radio" value="Test1">
              Test1
          </div>
     </div>
   <div class="row padding-4">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <input id="SecondaryDiscipline" name="SecondaryDiscipline" type="radio" value="Test2">
              Test2
          </div>
     </div>
   <div class="row padding-4">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <input id="SecondaryDiscipline" name="SecondaryDiscipline" type="radio" value="Test3">
              Test3
          </div>
     </div>
```

I tried below both. I select first one below code is working. other than that it is not working

method 1#

```
 $("#SecondaryDiscipline").each(function (i, x) {
                        if ($(x).is(":checked")) {
                            $(x).removeAttr("checked");
                        }
                    });
```

method 2

```
$('#SecondaryDiscipline').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Same ID for multiple elements?

Comment: They aren't even checked to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$('[name="SecondaryDiscipline"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Also, note that you should not have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

- Your id `#SecondaryDiscipline` is repeating. Its not correct.
- You can make that a class. ie `<input class="SecondaryDiscipline" name="SecondaryDiscipline" type="radio" value="Test1">`

Then both the method will work fine

- Another method is selecting by name. `$('input[name=SecondaryDiscipline]')`

Comment: That is what I wrote... It is not correct.

Comment: edited .. good sugestion